Calculating variance of gradient of barren plateau problem in quantum variational circuit
In paper Cost function dependent barren plateaus in shallow
parametrized quantum circuits, the author exhibit an warm-up example in page 2 to show the barren plateau phenomenon. In this example, the author presented cost function and global cost function. Then the variance of global gradient is . It is pretty confusing to me about getting the result of this variance, can someone please help me with this calculation?
I have assumed that the variance should be , and the estimation of x should be , but it is not correct for me to imply these equitions.
